# Laravel passport library environment variable problem on Cloud Run

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-run

I'm using the passport library on my laravel 8 project and I have a problem because I can't use the default command to generate my file `php artisan passport:install` because I'm on Cloud Run serverless and I have to use the environment variables.

So I see this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#loading-keys-from-the-environment

It works on my local environment when I send the variables through docker compose with `APP_ENV=production` declared but when I running on my production server in Cloud Run I have this error:

```
exception: "LogicException"
file: "/app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php"
line: 67
message: "Unable to read key from file -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY...
```

I don't understand why passport want a file on Cloud Run and not get the server env vars. I tested to remove all carriage return in my private and public keys but it doesn't work. Maybe the format is bad in my yaml ? I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Run the **php artisan** commands in your Dockerfile while generating the container image. Do not try to configure Laravel from the deployed container (running in Cloud Run). You should also do the normal Artisan cache commands while creating the container.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your answer. Yes the cache command `php artisan optimize` is in my entrypoint and it's ok. And for `php artisan passport:install` I can't place it inside the Dockerfile because this command write into the database and the database is not reachable from the Dockerfile. But if I run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config` in my Dockerfile to use the server env vars I'll don't get any build error but it has no effect and I get the LogicException error when I call a web service

Comment: You will need to temporarily make the database available. Otherwise, you would need to setup Laravel every time Cloud Run starts. That also means you cannot run cache commands in your Dockerfile as the environment does not yet exist. You must design for Cloud Run as a stateless container service and not try to configure once the container starts up.

Comment: @JohnHanley I see what you mean but I don't know how I can run cache commands in the Dockerfile because the cache files will be init with the local env variables and I run my build in Cloud Build there is no env set at this point. And for the database I'm searching how I can temporarily make Cloud SQL available when Cloud Build is building my image but I can't find how I can do that

Comment: I recommend that you get each of the steps working from your local development system. Once that is working, move to Cloud Build. The way you are trying to configure Laravel will not work and it will be faster to figure that out locally. For example, you must run all of the Laravel commands while creating the container - which is one step in Cloud Build. Do not set ENTRYPOINT to **php artisan** commands. Those commands execute when the container starts. Instead, those commands need to be **RUN** statements in the Dockerfile. Find a good tutorial on Docker + Laravel.

Comment: I once got the same error, and the fix was to use double quotes `"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"` instead of single quotes `'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'`. Also, make sure to remove this line from your codebase (if it exists) `Passport::loadKeysFrom`. As per your screenshot, you are using the regular Cloud Run environment variables to store the keys. As a best practice, I would suggest moving them to the Secret Manager and letting Cloud Run have references to those secrets. It's easy and safe. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#console

Comment: @metad00r Oh really with double quotes ! I'll try that tomorrow I hope it will work thank you. Yeah I seen secret manager but I think it's expensive because the quota is 10k access / month. So each time a web service will be called it will count 1 access. So if I got 1 millions web service request per month I'll pay lot of access over 10k. Or maybe I don't understand something about the secret manager pricing ?

Comment: @John regarding Secret Manager it is $0.03 per 10K operations per month and the first 10K operations are free each month. So if you have 20K operations you will be billed 10K operations which is $0.03. For 1 million operations you will be billed around $2.97 for the specific month for one version of the private and public keys. See https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=94ab7eea-846a-44c6-b969-616c3e126f8c

Comment: @metad00r Ok so it works well by using a secret manager but it doesn't work if I set double quotes. Cloud run reformat automatically the double quotes to single quote :/ so I'll use the secret manager. And it's safer :p thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking closer at your screenshot I think I see why the cert validation is failing.

In `CryptKey.php` this line `$this->isValidKey($keyPath, $this->passPhrase ?? '')` is returning `false` because of the missing `\n` (new lines) in your keys, resulting in `"Unable to read key from file -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----..."`. Certificates need to be in a certain format, and that's currently not the case using those environment variables.

If possible, change this invalid format in your secret:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MIIJQgIBADANBgk...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

To:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQgIBADANBgk...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If that doesn't work you should also try:

- Importing the certs as files instead of using the textarea in Secret Manager
- Or, use `\n` explicitly in the textarea

PS. My private cert starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` instead of `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`